# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'recipes' of 'props' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, destructuring

I am a beginner in reactjs when I tried to run a program it showed the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'recipes' of 'props' as it is undefined.
    at RecipeList (bundle.js:532:5)
    at renderWithHooks (bundle.js:22834:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (bundle.js:25596:17)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:26795:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:11784:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:11833:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:11893:35)
    at beginWork$1 (bundle.js:31635:11)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:30471:16)
    at workLoopSync (bundle.js:30408:9)
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: when i tried to add my code it's showing ```
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your assignments is not properly transferred to a component, that is why it is "Undefined".

Upload the parts of the code related to this props code or alternative try it yourself with console.log(props): check what is defined and what is not.
Then connect the two.

Comment: ```export default function RecipeList({ props }) {
  const{
   recipes,handleRecipeAdd,handleRecipeDelete
  }=props```

Comment: export default function RecipeList({ recipes, handleRecipeAdd, handleRecipeDelete  }) {}; is the proper way to do destructuring

Comment: Can you please explain why did you put empty braces before the semi colon.
Iam a beginner sorry if the question was very amatuer

Comment: It was just an example. The rest of your function scope should be inside the {}.
I'm sorry if it misleading you. The point was to show you the way to destructuring your array.
So it should be.

export default function RecipeList({ recipes, handleRecipeAdd, handleRecipeDelete }) {
HERE YOUR FUNCTION SHOULD BE
}

If you will upload the code to a repository I will gladly try to help you more.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it worked. Can you please explain what I did wrong in destructuring and how did you correct those mistakes?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Glad to help!.
Kinda like having a box with many games, your "props" box.
If you ask someone to get your "game box," they will understand since you declared you have your props box, your "gameBox," which contains many objects. However, if you want the Lego, you need to re-construct your instructions.
const { lego }  = gameBox;
Only now, when you ask for your Lego from someone, someone will know that this Lego is a part of your game box. You have de-structured = the process of unpacking something small from the main part.
And please, don't forget to mark this as the answer.
:)

Comment: Thank You!, So I need to list everything inside the argument instead of assigning it to a variable like props and putting that variable as an argument. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not quite understand that.

Comment: So what I did was I passed the objects recipes, handleRecipeAdd, handleRecipeDelete to the props and assigned it as an argument for the function RecipeList but you asked me to assign every object in the argument section itself instead of passing it to the props. Is this right?. Sorry if I am wrong, I have just started learning react and I am a beginner in this and Thank you for your help.

Comment: All good. We are both in the same situation.
I am not sure if the word argument is entirely correct in this situation. Since in some sort of a way, those are some arguments but the action we did here is called "Destructuring" which is isolating your variables from an array.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you used `const { recipes } = props` in your code, however, props are undefined, so you get the error `destructure property`.

Can you put your code there? And check that the props are not undefined. Check parent component send useful data to child component.

Comment: I am not able to put out my full code here can i share the repository link here??

Comment: Of course you can